# filter input string

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I faced with problem filtering string when i insert data into my table. I mean special characters like `'` `<` etc i can do simple replace but i need to save the original sequence of characters. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: can you provide your code to better understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the string through code you could specify an array of characters to strip from the string.  The String.Join can use the split method to remove those characters and put it back together

```
    string s = "He<llo;< I -am a $stri-ng;";

    // Add other characters that you deem unacceptable
    char[] invalidChars = { ';', '<', '>', '-' };
    s = String.Join("", s.Split(invalidChars));
```

In terms of saving the original sequence, this is very vague so I'm not sure what you mean but what pops into my mind is to use the database and create a second column so that you have one for what they entered in, and another for the fixed value.  Two ways pop into my head to control this

1. Database Trigger -
   Design some function to strip away characters and save to the 
   fixed value column.  The risk in this is that if someone decides to key a character you have not trapped yet you would not only modify the function but have to run this function against any record that slipped by
2. Computed Column Specification -
   Create an expression based on the function to strip off
   characters and let the column control this value
   This is sufficient enough to defeat the risk added through the trigger.  When you modify the function since this is a computed column it would in theory update the value. (Correct me if I am wrong here, not tested, just in theory)

Probably not the most efficient approaches but this is what I would use with my current toolset.

Comment: Yup thx for unswer but its not exacly what i need. If we looking tools for administrating sqlite (like http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/ ). We see that we can add to fields characters like < ' etc. The main question how it realize, it's sqlite function or user defined. For example to prevent sql injection in mysql+php we can use mysql_real_escape_string